# Imported .csv file plotting incorrectly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, csv, plotting

I have imported a csv into ArcGIS, then displayed xy data. For some unknown reason to me, the point are plotting incorrectly. I am using an ESRI base map in WGS 84 web mercator aux sphere and the display is set to decimal degrees.  When I mouse over the correct position in ArcGIS the bottom right coordinates of the mouse match the imported csv properties.
[image]

If I search using the coordinates in Find locations in ArcGIS, it plots indicates correctly, but the same point imported in via a csv does not as shown in the below image:

[image]

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like it is plotting on "Null Island", suggesting that coordinates are being interpreted as 0,0

Comment: When you created your event layer did you set the coordinate system to be WGS84?

Comment: I opened the base map so the workspace took on the WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere. I then brought in the csv and in the display xy data it indicated WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere in the description.

Comment: Just to add to the confusion, I have brought the same csv into QGIS and it plots correctly. I then exported the points from QGIS as a shp file and this plots correctly in ArcGIS, but still not the csv when brought in directly to ArcGIS.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the workflow below:

1. Launch a new blank map document
2. Follow [this](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/adding-x-y-coordinate-data-as-a-layer.htm) to add the X, Y data in ArcMap
3. Make sure that the Lat and Long are set correctly, and as the values(**-0.425, 51.47**) are in a geographic coordinate system, specify **WGS 1984** as the coordinate system
4. Once the data is added, add the Basemap to confirm the location